# Make html5 input[type=range] with many steps snap to the middle

Tags: jquery, angularjs, input

I have an `<input type=range>` with a large number of allowed steps (in the range of 60,000).

Some of steps (for instance the mid-point) are more relevant and I would like a caret/snap to when the user moves close to them. How can I do that?

I am using the Angular and jQuery libraries.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is a HTML5 feature that provides detent-snapping natively, using the `list` attribute and matching `datalist` element. Each element in the list becomes a detent point in the slider, with a tick-mark as well as snapping.

```html
<input type="range" value="0" min="0" max="60000" step="1" list="my-detents">

<datalist id="my-detents">
  <option value="30000">
</datalist>
```

The `datalist` element can be placed anywhere in the HTML; it’s just defining the list (here named `my-detents`) for use by the `input` element.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist) and [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#feat=datalist), as of February 2019, use of `datalist` with `range` inputs is supported by Chrome, IE, Edge, and preview versions of Safari. (Firefox supports `datalist` for `text` inputs only.)

Comment: As of 2023, Safari happily supports it too.

Answer (score 0):

Not to sure what you've tried so far or what your actual goal is. But my understanding is you want it to select the middle value if a value that is in the middle third of the range is selected. Here is my example.

HTML:

```
<input id="slider1" type="range" min="0" max="500" step="20" />
```

JQuery:

```
$('#slider1').change( function() {
    var cVal =  $(this).val(); 
    if (cVal >= 200 && cVal <= 300) {
        $('#slider1').val("250");
    }
});
```

So if once changed it equals anywhere between 200 and 300 it will default to 250. Problem here is it sets the value to 250 not just the caretPosition. You can change all the settings as you need though. There is a plugin which I have not used before called [jQuery Caret](https://gist.github.com/DrPheltRight/1007907) that might be better help if you want to keep the selected value and just change the position but once again I have not used it.